# Longest element inside viewport

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to set 'active' class to most visible element on page. With this code, I was able to set 'active' class the elements that appear on the page.

I'm doing this for my infinite scroll project. If I can give active class to my target element i can change page url and title for social media share process.

```js
    $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  $('article').each(function() {
    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<article>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>Text...
    ..
    .</p>
</article>
<article>
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <p>Text2...
    ..
    .</p>
</article>
<article>
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <p>Text2...
    ..
    .</p>
</article>
   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you consider *"most visible"*? Could have a long article with title not showing above a short one that shows completely but takes up less of viewport for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is most visible, but you can use a flag that indicates if a visible element was found, reset all the elements and set active class to the first you found.

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom && elementTop > viewportTop;
};


$(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
  var activeFound = false;
  $('article').each(function() {
    if (!activeFound) {
      if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
        $("article.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        activeFound = true;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <p>Text... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Text2... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Text2... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <p>Text... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Text2... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Text2... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <p>Text... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Text2... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Text2... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <p>Text... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Text2... .. .
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Text2... .. .
  </p>
</article>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$("*")` is expensive,  especially inside a scroll handler Probably better as `$("article.active").removeClass`

Comment: I'm trying to change page meta settings and url with this method. Otherwise when i share an page on facebook/twitter or etc, it takes only first article's information.